# Not of hexadecimal value 0xffff?

Tags: c++, c, hex, objective-c-category

I guess the output should be "0000" but it's ffff as Not of ~ffff->0000 0000 0000 0000

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a=0xffff;
    ~a;
    printf("%x\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A helpful hint - compiling with -Wall in gcc will warn you when you have statement that have no effect. "thing.c:6:3: warning: statement with no effect".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Tim and Vlad said, you aren't doing anything with the bit-wise inversion.

Even if you change the code to `a = ~a;`, you may not get zero.  That's because if `unsigned int` has more than 16 bits, you'll have leading zeros, which become 1's after inversion.

So I expect your output to be

> FFFF0000

or even

> FFFFFFFFFFFF0000

If you want 16-bit bitwise operations, you can use

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uint16_t a;
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to assign the value back to `a`:

```
a = ~a;
```

Even then, the outputted value can look like this, due to the size of the datatype:

```
ffff0000
```

To make it work as expected (all 0s), set the initial value of `a` to `UINT_MAX` (from `limits.h`). Doing so sets all the bits to `1`.

Comment: Ya i have done that too and the output is "ffff0000" i can't understand the logic.

Comment: You could also set the initial value to `~0`

Answer (score 7):

Writing `~a;` has no effect. It's an expression which returns the complement of `a`, but doesn't change `a` itself.

You want `a = ~a;`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't assign the value to a.  You need a = ~a;

Answer (score 1):

`~a` by itself is a statement that returns the bitwise complement of `a`. You can either assign a to `~a` (as @timcooper suggests), or you can

```
printf("%xn", ~a);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you need to either assign the value back into a with `a = ~a;` or print the result directly with `printf("%x\n",~a);` but in either case, you are still not going to get zero as you expect.

The ~ operator will flip all the bits in the variable.  Since you are most likely dealing with 32-bit integers, you are going to end up with `0xFFFF0000` because those upper 16 bits will be flipped from zero's to one's.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short int a= 0xffff;
    a=~a;
    printf("%x\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more context around your suggested code.